# Craft3 CMS Website Search form is not updating results if I do a new search?

Tags: craft3, search

I'm upgrading a website from Craft2 to Craft3 on the previous website I implemented website search and work without any issues, but on the new site, I can do an initial search and get results without any problems if I decide to do a second search the results are not updating only show me the results from the previous search.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by "a second search"? It sounds like your search form might be incorrectly set up if you're not seeing results update on submission.

Comment: I have a search form on the website navigation for visitors to be able to search the site. Let say I search the site for the term apple, I get back results, but if I decide to change the search term to banana, I don't get the new results because the page only shows me the result for apple my first search.

Comment: If searching for "banana" the first time gives you different results to searching for "apple" then there is either be an issue with how your form submits, or perhaps the search results (or the entire search page) are being cached. Are you using any form of caching?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Caching was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It became apparent from the comments (to the question, see above) that caching was to blame.